# dropdown toggle not working from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a basic dropdown menu with twitter bootstrap. When I click on the button that opens the dropdown menu, everything works fine.

The problem is, when I try to toggle dropdown by clicking some other element on the page (I need this functionality)

```
$(document).on("click", ".drop-toggle", function(e) {
    console.log("working");
    $(".btn-group").toggleClass("open");
});
```

I can see console message, but nothing happens.

When I simply call

```
$(".btn-group").toggleClass("open");
```

it works, but it doesn't work from the event handler. Any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/P2RnW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation.

```
$(document).on("click", ".drop-toggle", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-menu").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2RnW/1/

Comment: i will try it @home, but it seems to be working. will mark as answered if it's all right :)